# use regular expression for phone no

Tags: regex

I am using following lines of code

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone">
          <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server">
              <%# Regex.Replace(Eval("Phone").ToString(), @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "($1)-$2-$3") %>
            </asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

It is formatting numbers like 9419002345 but not numbers like 1408-464-1680 or 463237062... Please help me in writing accurate regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your regular expression just matches when there are ten digits. Your `463237062` has only 9.

You should make the algorithm allow matching on 9 digits too, for example like this:

```
@"(\d{1,3})(\d{3})(\d{4})"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
`(\d{10})`  will compare 10 numbers
OR
`4 digits`-`3 digits`-`4 digits`.

```
(\d{10})|(\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4})
```

Adjust number of digits as per your need.